# Setting the background to the google-charts, chart. Doesn't do anything

Tags: html, web, google-visualization

I draw a column chart, using the google-charts API. When i set the background to the chart it doesn't do anything.

[image]

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $str ?>);

    var options = {
    title: 'Business Optimization Per Predicted Conversion Rate',
    bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    colors: ['purple','red'],
    fontSize:20,
    legend: { position: "none" },
    width: 900,

    };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

What's happened i wrote specific in option tag that the background need to be red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing :

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Try doing :

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

What happens here is that you're probably using material charts and the way options are defined has changed.

See this note from the [google charts documentation regarding this, here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Material) :

> The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are
>   largely final, but the way options are declared is not. If you are
>   converting a Classic Column Chart to a Material Column Chart, you'll
>   want to replace this line:
>
> chart.draw(data, options);
>
> ...with this:
>
> chart.draw(data, google.charts.Column.convertOptions(options));